# jquery button click not working second time on fieldset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fieldset

I have 11 FieldSet using and also have 11 buttons for skipping purpose,

Html

```
<button id="skip1">1</button>
<button id="skip2">2</button>
<button id="skip3">3</button>
```

Jquery

```
$("#skip1").click(function(){
    alert("In1")
        $("#field_1").show();
    });
$("#skip2").click(function(){
    alert("In2")
        $("#field_2").show();
    });

    $("#skip3").click(function(){
    alert("In3")
        $("#field_3").show();
    });
```

The First time they working fine another time didn't work, only throw the alert Otherwise If possible to skip fieldset? Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: do you want to keep open obly one fieldset at a time ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: alert only came fieldset not show @Regis Portalez

Comment: skip 1 or skip2 button after second click the fieldset 3 only show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the :button selector and the fieldsets ids and assuming that the text remains just the numbers (this will also work if it is the id or on a data-attribute or value if the code is changed appropriately), on the onclick of the button the following code will hide all fieldsets and only show the one matching the id of the clicked button. Note that since there are 11 fieldsets and buttons to account for - this will allow all buttons and fieldsets to be controlled from the one piece of code. Note I just dummied up some fieldsets for demo purposes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(":button").click(function() {
                    var id=$(this).text();
                    alert("In"+id);
                    $('fieldset').hide();
                    $('#field_'+ id).show();
                });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="skip1">1</button>
<button id="skip2">2</button>
<button id="skip3">3</button>

 <form>
  <fieldset id="field_1">
    <legend>test 1:</legend>
    Name 1: <input type="text"><br>
    Email 1: <input type="text"><br>
    </fieldset>
   
     <fieldset id="field_2">
    <legend>test 2:</legend>
    Name 2: <input type="text"><br>
    Email 2: <input type="text"><br>
    </fieldset>
   
     <fieldset id="field_3">
    <legend>test 3:</legend>
    Name 3: <input type="text"><br>
    Email 3: <input type="text"><br>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks @udayakumarb - i enjoy trying to help. I would recommend that you use a data-attribute or a value  or even the button id as the trigger for it thiough. You will probably not want to leave it as 1,2,3 etc on the button text. Good luck with it.

Comment: One thing to note though - just because the inputs are hidden- does not mean that they will not submit when you submit the form. They will -even if they are empty.  If that is an issue - you may be better to remove all fieldsets and inouts from the form and build it dynamically - including only those inpputs that you want to submit. Happy coding :))

Answer (score 0):

write your jquery inside document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#skip1").click(function() {
        alert("In1")
        $("#field_1").show();
    });
    $("#skip2").click(function() {
        alert("In2")
        $("#field_2").show();
    });

    $("#skip3").click(function() {
        alert("In3")
        $("#field_3").show();
    });
})
```

JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/euftx1a6/

Answer (score 0):

show one fieldset and hide others using hide().Try this:

```
$("#skip1").click(function(){
       $("#field_1").show();
       $("#field_2").hide();
       $("#field_3").hide();
});
$("#skip2").click(function(){
      $("#field_2").show();
      $("#field_1").hide();
      $("#field_3").hide();
});
$("#skip3").click(function(){
      $("#field_3").show();
      $("#field_1").hide();
      $("#field_2").hide();
});
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks @Dhara parmar, I'm the new one its working fine thanks to all

Comment: problem with this is the OP states that there are 11 fields / buttons - this will lead t a really long chunk of code. look at my option for a shorter alternative